# I keep getting error: PHP Startup - libphp5.so missing? PHP seems to run fine with Apache

Tags: php5

My linux distro is Arch Linux. I first noticed this error when trying to send emails using the PHP `mail()` function. Testing with a simple mail-test.php file with the `mail()` function sends the email when called from the command line, but will not send when using http://localhost/mail-test.php. I get the same error both times, but only using the command line sends the email.

I get the error:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/libphp5.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at Unknown#0

Using `ls /usr/lib/php/modules` shows the file does not exist, and searching the system results in `/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so` existing.

php-apache is installed and apache serves php sites just fine. (tested with a test php file containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`)

I can't seem to find the cause of this error though. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Take a loot at `/etc/php5/` there should be some config files in there to help you.

Comment: I have tried to move the file to `/usr/lib/php/modules` but doing so results in the library not loading with error `undefined symbol: ap_server_root`

Comment: @DanielSanchez don't recommend moving things that could potentially break a system. If you have to, symlink them. However, config files and library paths are there for a reason.

Comment: @SailorCire `/etc/php5` does not exist in my system. `/etc/php` contains a php.ini which is the default except where I changed `sendmail_path` to use my MTA. There is also a `conf.d` directory but that is empty

Answer (score 1):

I have an Arch Linux web server. Looks like my configuration files are way out of date.

However, looking at the [ArchWiki Apache HTTP Server page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server), the section named "PHP" says that you'll need to do some changes to both `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and `/etc/php/php.ini` to get things to work. If I were in your shoes, I'd probably do `pacman -R php-apache` and maybe even `pacman -R apache`, and then re-install both of those packages. Save copies of files you made, and clean up what `pacman` complains about.

After re-installing, I'd fix up `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and `/etc/php/php.ini` exactly as the ArchWiki page says to. Then do `systemctl start httpd` and see if your problem has gone away. I suspect that you've got some mismatched config files, and maybe even something wrong with LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the `http` user. Doing the uninstall and reinstall will hopefully get those inconsistencies back in synch.

Comment: I followed all of this advice and upon re-installing php-apache and apache I now get the error `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so' - /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: ap_server_root in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: @PancakeMaker - `ap_server_root` is a .BSS segment symbol (C language global variable) in `httpd`: `nm -D /usr/bin/httpd| grep ap_server_root ` Are you certain you have a good installation of Apache? Is the `ServerRoot` value set in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, and is it correct?

Comment: After using `pacman -R` and cleaning up the results I re-installed both packages and set the new config files exactly according to the Arch wiki. Upon testing the new installation php immediately threw out the same error I mentioned before. `ServerRoot` has always been set to `"/etc/httpd"` which is the default value.

Comment: @PancakeMaker - do `nm -D /usr/bin/httpd | grep ap_server_root` to see if the Apache executable even has that symbol defined in it. Also, is package "httpd" up to date? `pacman -S httpd` should show you.

Comment: @Bruck Ediger `nm -D /usr/bin/httpd | grep ap_server_root` outputs `000000000068a4e8 B ap_server_root` My system does not have an "httpd" package installed and it isn't listed in the Arch repos either. I am not experienced with the deeper workings of Arch (why I started to use it) so I apologize if I do not adequately provide info

Comment: @PancakeMaker - my mistake.  It's the "apache" package. Try un-installing and re-installing "apache". `pacman -Q apache` tells me "apache 2.4.12-4"

Comment: I see. `pacman -Q apache` also tells me "apache 2.4.12-4" I re-installed Apache using `pacman -S apache` before making my first post here. It unfortunately did not change anything. I also removed apache using `pacman -R apache` and then wiped the system clean of all Apache configs and libraries that were not dependencies of other packages. Following this I re-installed Apache and PHP and only changed configs need to get the two working together as shown in the Arch Wiki

Comment: @PancakeMaker - last things I can think of is to look in /var/log/httpd/error_log  when you run the PHP script from the web.  You may also want to go into /etc/php/php.ini and turn up error reporting: "error_reporting = E_ALL" and "display_errors = On" and "display_startup_errors = On". That might give you some extra info to go on. Also: now that you're getting a different error, open a new question, complete with version numbers for all the packages involved, and the smallest piece of PHP that triggers the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I will dig around some more before opening a new question to see if I can find the root issue.